# Jquery Toggle doesnt work (it hides my toggle button somehow)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-animate

Im using Bootstrap 3 for making a responsive admin dashboard.
So i created a button for show and hide the sidebar.
Somehow the when i load my page it hides my toggle button and the toggle event doenst work at all.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-toggle-sidebar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
</div>

<div class="sidebar-left">

</div>


<div class="page-content">

</div>
```

Jquery (With jqueryUI)

```
 $(".btn-toggle-sidebar").toggle(function() {           
            $(".sidebar-left").animate({left: -220}, 500);
            $(".page-content").animate({marginLeft: 0}, 500);                       
        }, function() {         
            $(".sidebar-left").animate({left: 0}, 500);
            $(".page-content").animate({marginLeft: 220}, 500);             
        });
```

Comment: `toggle()` does just that, toggles an element's visibility. You probably want to use `click()` instead.

Comment: make sure you put your above javascript within ready handler
    `$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    });`

Comment: Okey how i do it in a click event when i click it again it comes back again ?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: the `toggle()` event you are using is deprecated now. You need to use `click()`. Current `toggle()` function hides/shows

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn-toggle-sidebar").click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(".sidebar-left").animate({left: 0}, 500);
            $(".page-content").animate({marginLeft: 220}, 500); 
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(".sidebar-left").animate({left: -220}, 500);
            $(".page-content").animate({marginLeft: 0}, 500);
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

This should do it for you. (Although I may have got the animations the wrong way around)